# How do I fill a ListView in android with a varying number of XML, and pull data from the list?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to create a sort of bracket app for a game club in my school, but I am having a lot of trouble with just the first activity. I would like to have a list of input boxes for player names, and the ability to press a button to add more players (more input boxes in the list), and have the names  from the boxes be carried over to the next activity, in which each item in the list will have a player name (textView) and another input box for that player's score that round, which will finally be carried over to the final activity that will display the list of players that will be moving on to the next round.

I thought about creating multiple XMLs for varying numbers of players, but that will limit the number of players that can play in a game, and would also mean I would have to make 3 XMLs for each number of players (editText, textView & editText, textView).

So far, I have this:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bracketapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        players.add( new Player() );
        players.add( new Player() );

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Player>(
                 this, R.layout.player_row,
                 R.id.textView1, ));
    }

    public void createPlayer() {
        players.add( new Player() );
    }
}
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/Main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bAdd"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.44" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:minWidth="125dp"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:text="@string/Main.Play"
        android:onClick="play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bPlay"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bPlay"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:minWidth="125dp"
        android:onClick="addPlayer"
        android:text="@string/Main.Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Player.java

```
package com.example.bracketapp;

public class Player {
    String name;
    int points;

    public Player(){
        name = null;
        points = 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int newPoints){
        points = newPoints;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

}
```

and player_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:text="Player Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know if it's very clear here, but I have absolutely no idea what I am doing, and would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: The `ArrayAdapter` seems to have the methods `add`/`insert` which might do what you want (adding another item to the list). Otherwise add a new Player to the ArrayList and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.

Comment: My issue is having the items actually show up in the ListView, not managing the data of the Players